# Need of an intuitive proof of an algebraic theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While learning fraction decomposition I have introduced the following algebraic theorem but I don't know its proof.

> **Theorem:**
>   Any polynomial can be written as the product of linear factors and irreducible quadratic factors.

Can anyone please prove and explain the proof with intuition and examples?

Comment: I think you want polynomials and coefficients over $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

From the fundamental theorem of algebra, any polynomial $f$ with real coefficients can be factored as

$$f(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)\dots(x-r_n).$$

Since $f$ has real coefficients, $f(\bar x)=\overline{f(x)}$, so

$$a(\bar x-r_1)(\bar x-r_2)\dots(\bar x-r_n)=\bar a(\bar x-\bar r_1)(\bar x-\bar r_2)\dots(\bar x-\bar r_n).$$

Since $a$ is the leading coefficient, which is real by assumption, $\bar a=a$, and the roots on the left and right must be equal up to a permutation by the factor theorem (or unique factorization in $\Bbb C[x]$). Labeling those $r_i$ which are equal to their conjugates by $s_i$ and those which are not in pairs as $\alpha_i,\bar\alpha_i$, we get

\begin{align}
f(x)&=a(x-s_1)\dots(x-s_k)(x-\alpha_1)(x-\bar\alpha_1)\dots(x-\alpha_m)(x-\bar\alpha_m)\\
&=a(x-s_1)\dots(x-s_k)(x^2-2\Re[\alpha_1]x+|\alpha_1|^2)\dots(x^2-2\Re[\alpha_m]x+|\alpha_m|^2),\\
\end{align}

and this is our desired factorization, because the elements $x-s_i$ are linear real factors (since $s_i=\bar s_i$), and the quadratic terms $x^2-2\Re[\alpha_i]x+|\alpha_i|^2$ are real since $2\Re[\alpha_i],|\alpha_i|^2$ are real, and they are irreducible because their factorization $(x-\alpha_i)(x-\bar\alpha_i)$ contains complex coefficients.

For example, $x^5-1$ has the five roots $r_k=e^{2\pi ik/5}$, so its complex factorization is

$$x^5-1=(x-e^{-4\pi i/5})(x-e^{-2\pi i/5})(x-1)(x-e^{2\pi i/5})(x-e^{4\pi i/5}).$$

We pair up the conjugates $e^{2\pi i/5},e^{-2\pi i/5}$ and $e^{4\pi i/5},e^{-4\pi i/5}$, and the real root $1$ stays as it is, to get

\begin{align}
x^5-1&=(x-1)(x^2-(e^{2\pi i/5}+e^{-2\pi i/5})x+1)(x^2-(e^{4\pi i/5}+e^{-4\pi i/5})x+1)\\
&=(x-1)\left(x^2-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}5\right)x+1\right)\left(x^2-2\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}5\right)x+1\right),\\
\end{align}

which is our desired real factorization of $x^5-1$.

Comment: I can not understand some terms and expression:

Comment: They are: 1.Since $f$ has real coefficients, $f(\bar x)=\overline{f(x)}$, so

$$a(\bar x-r_1)(\bar x-r_2)\dots(x-r_n)=\bar a(\bar x-\bar r_1)(\bar x-\bar r_2)\dots(\bar x-\bar r_n).$$ what do you mean by $f(\bar x)=\overline{f(x)}$.Why have you written it.

Comment: Please explain the statement: Labeling those $r_i$ which are equal to their conjugates by $s_i$ and those which are not in pairs as $\alpha_i,\bar\alpha_i$, we get

Comment: @Shahedalmamun $f(\bar x)$ is $f$ applied to the complex conjugate of $x$. A real polynomial satisfies $f(\bar x)=\overline{f(x)}$ because if you write it out as $\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ the left side is $\sum_{i=0}^na_i\bar x^i$ and the right is $\sum_{i=0}^n\bar a_i\bar x^i$, and since the $a_i$ are real $\bar a_i=a_i$. In the answer I expanded each side of $f(\bar x)=\overline{f(x)}$ using the expression $f(x)=a\prod_{i=1}^n(x-r_i)$ on each side to deduce properties of $\{r_i\}$.

Comment: @Shahedalmamun The list $\{r_i\}$ contains a collection of complex numbers, and in the previous sentence I showed that the complex conjugate of each number in the list is also in the list. Thus every number can be paired up with its complex conjugate, which is also in the list, unless it is equal to its own complex conjugate, which only happens if $r_i$ is real. This allows me to partition the roots into two groups, one for the real numbers $s_i$ which are equal to their conjugates, and one for the pairs $\alpha_i,\bar\alpha_i$ such that $\alpha_i\ne\bar\alpha_i$.